# How to get the first time a date is entered in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL table that is used to hold all the updates to another table. Every time something in the other table is updated this `Shadow` table gets a new row with all of the data from before the update. It looks something like this:

```
+--------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+
| cd_POLineItemScheduledShipDate |        CreatedOn        |        UpdatedOn        | _rescd_PurchaseOrderLine |
+--------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+
| 2017-08-18 00:00:00.000        | 2017-08-15 11:14:00.623 | 2017-08-24 14:49:45.850 | 037-01714223-REF-1       |
| 2017-08-18 00:00:00.000        | 2017-08-11 11:13:31.553 | 2017-08-24 14:48:52.287 | 037-01714223-REF-1       |
| 2017-08-18 00:00:00.000        | 2017-08-11 11:13:44.007 | 2017-08-24 14:48:45.927 | 037-01714223-REF-1       |
| 2017-08-18 00:00:00.000        | 2017-08-11 11:13:28.833 | 2017-08-24 14:48:39.287 | 037-01714223-REF-1       |
| 2017-08-18 00:00:00.000        | 2017-08-11 11:13:48.490 | 2017-08-24 14:48:32.847 | 037-01714223-REF-1       |
| 2017-08-18 00:00:00.000        | 2017-08-11 11:13:39.410 | 2017-08-24 14:48:26.253 | 037-01714223-REF-1       |
| 2017-08-18 00:00:00.000        | 2017-08-11 11:13:44.007 | 2017-08-24 14:47:56.753 | 037-01714223-REF-1       |
| 2017-08-18 00:00:00.000        | 2017-08-11 11:13:28.833 | 2017-08-24 14:47:56.723 | 037-01714223-REF-1       |
| 2017-08-18 00:00:00.000        | 2017-08-11 11:13:48.490 | 2017-08-24 14:47:56.660 | 037-01714223-REF-1       |
| 2017-08-18 00:00:00.000        | 2017-08-11 11:13:31.553 | 2017-08-24 14:47:56.630 | 037-01714223-REF-1       |
| 2017-08-18 00:00:00.000        | 2017-08-11 11:13:39.410 | 2017-08-24 14:47:56.567 | 037-01714223-REF-1       |
| NULL                           | 2017-08-15 11:14:00.623 | 2017-08-15 14:03:15.067 | 037-01714223-REF-1       |
| NULL                           | 2017-08-11 11:13:36.537 | 2017-08-14 12:45:13.103 | 037-01714223-REF-1       |
| NULL                           | 2017-08-11 11:13:45.363 | 2017-08-14 12:45:05.057 | 037-01714223-REF-1       |
| NULL                           | 2017-08-11 11:13:44.007 | 2017-08-14 12:44:58.027 | 037-01714223-REF-1       |
| NULL                           | 2017-08-11 11:13:28.833 | 2017-08-14 12:44:50.620 | 037-01714223-REF-1       |
| NULL                           | 2017-08-11 11:13:48.490 | 2017-08-14 12:44:43.387 | 037-01714223-REF-1       |
| NULL                           | 2017-08-11 11:13:31.553 | 2017-08-14 12:44:36.353 | 037-01714223-REF-1       |
| NULL                           | 2017-08-11 11:13:39.410 | 2017-08-14 12:44:28.450 | 037-01714223-REF-1       |
| NULL                           | 2017-08-11 11:13:40.113 | 2017-08-14 12:44:21.230 | 037-01714223-REF-1       |
| NULL                           | 2017-08-11 11:13:45.990 | 2017-08-14 12:44:13.730 | 037-01714223-REF-1       |
| NULL                           | 2017-08-11 11:13:41.240 | 2017-08-14 12:44:06.823 | 037-01714223-REF-1       |
| NULL                           | 2017-08-11 11:13:41.457 | 2017-08-14 12:43:59.370 | 037-01714223-REF-1       |
| NULL                           | 2017-08-11 11:13:37.553 | 2017-08-14 12:43:51.730 | 037-01714223-REF-1       |
| NULL                           | 2017-08-11 11:13:40.707 | 2017-08-14 12:43:44.527 | 037-01714223-REF-1       |
| 2017-08-18 00:00:00.000        | 2017-08-15 11:14:00.623 | 2017-08-24 14:49:45.850 | 037-01714223-REF-2       |
| 2017-08-18 00:00:00.000        | 2017-08-11 11:13:31.553 | 2017-08-24 14:48:52.287 | 037-01714223-REF-2       |
| 2017-08-18 00:00:00.000        | 2017-08-11 11:13:44.007 | 2017-08-24 14:48:45.927 | 037-01714223-REF-2       |
| 2017-08-18 00:00:00.000        | 2017-08-11 11:13:28.833 | 2017-08-24 14:48:39.287 | 037-01714223-REF-2       |
| 2017-08-18 00:00:00.000        | 2017-08-11 11:13:48.490 | 2017-08-24 14:48:32.847 | 037-01714223-REF-2       |
| 2017-08-18 00:00:00.000        | 2017-08-11 11:13:39.410 | 2017-08-24 14:48:26.253 | 037-01714223-REF-2       |
| 2017-08-18 00:00:00.000        | 2017-08-11 11:13:44.007 | 2017-08-24 14:47:56.753 | 037-01714223-REF-2       |
| 2017-08-18 00:00:00.000        | 2017-08-11 11:13:28.833 | 2017-08-24 14:47:56.723 | 037-01714223-REF-2       |
| 2017-08-18 00:00:00.000        | 2017-08-11 11:13:48.490 | 2017-08-24 14:47:56.660 | 037-01714223-REF-2       |
| 2017-08-18 00:00:00.000        | 2017-08-11 11:13:31.553 | 2017-08-24 14:47:56.630 | 037-01714223-REF-2       |
| 2017-08-18 00:00:00.000        | 2017-08-11 11:13:39.410 | 2017-08-24 14:47:56.567 | 037-01714223-REF-2       |
| NULL                           | 2017-08-15 11:14:00.623 | 2017-08-15 14:03:15.067 | 037-01714223-REF-2       |
| NULL                           | 2017-08-11 11:13:36.537 | 2017-08-14 12:45:13.103 | 037-01714223-REF-2       |
| NULL                           | 2017-08-11 11:13:45.363 | 2017-08-14 12:45:05.057 | 037-01714223-REF-2       |
| NULL                           | 2017-08-11 11:13:44.007 | 2017-08-14 12:44:58.027 | 037-01714223-REF-2       |
| NULL                           | 2017-08-11 11:13:28.833 | 2017-08-14 12:44:50.620 | 037-01714223-REF-2       |
| NULL                           | 2017-08-11 11:13:48.490 | 2017-08-14 12:44:43.387 | 037-01714223-REF-2       |
| NULL                           | 2017-08-11 11:13:31.553 | 2017-08-14 12:44:36.353 | 037-01714223-REF-2       |
| NULL                           | 2017-08-11 11:13:39.410 | 2017-08-14 12:44:28.450 | 037-01714223-REF-2       |
+--------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------+
```

So there are 2 different _rescd_PurchaseOrderLine numbers. Each one has several rows that have `NULL` for the cd_POLineItemScheduledShipDate and then several that are not null. (This is sorted by the `UpdatedOn desc`)

I am trying to get the `UpdatedOn` date from the row with the first instance of the cd_POLineItemScheduledShipDate not being `NULL` when ordered by the `UpdatedOn desc` for each Purchase Order Line. So for the example below I would expect the result to be:

```
+-------------------------+--------------------------+
|        UpdatedOn        | _rescd_PurchaseOrderLine |
+-------------------------+--------------------------+
| 2017-08-24 14:47:56.567 | 037-01714223-REF-1       |
| 2017-08-24 14:47:56.567 | 037-01714223-REF-2       |
+-------------------------+--------------------------+
```

I've tried a few things with `joins` and `groups` and using `max` or `min`, but I'm just not getting it.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you're after...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE #TestData;

CREATE TABLE #TestData (
    RN INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),  -- Need something to sort on that will hold the insert order...
    cd_POLineItemScheduledShipDate DATETIME NULL,
    CreatedOn DATETIME NOT NULL,
    UpdatedOn DATETIME NOT NULL,
    rescd_PurchaseOrderLine VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL 
    );
INSERT #TestData (cd_POLineItemScheduledShipDate, CreatedOn, UpdatedOn, rescd_PurchaseOrderLine) VALUES
    ('2017-08-18 00:00:00.000', '2017-08-15 11:14:00.623', '2017-08-24 14:49:45.850', '037-01714223-REF-1'),
    ('2017-08-18 00:00:00.000', '2017-08-11 11:13:31.553', '2017-08-24 14:48:52.287', '037-01714223-REF-1'),
    ('2017-08-18 00:00:00.000', '2017-08-11 11:13:44.007', '2017-08-24 14:48:45.927', '037-01714223-REF-1'),
    ('2017-08-18 00:00:00.000', '2017-08-11 11:13:28.833', '2017-08-24 14:48:39.287', '037-01714223-REF-1'),
    ('2017-08-18 00:00:00.000', '2017-08-11 11:13:48.490', '2017-08-24 14:48:32.847', '037-01714223-REF-1'),
    ('2017-08-18 00:00:00.000', '2017-08-11 11:13:39.410', '2017-08-24 14:48:26.253', '037-01714223-REF-1'),
    ('2017-08-18 00:00:00.000', '2017-08-11 11:13:44.007', '2017-08-24 14:47:56.753', '037-01714223-REF-1'),
    ('2017-08-18 00:00:00.000', '2017-08-11 11:13:28.833', '2017-08-24 14:47:56.723', '037-01714223-REF-1'),
    ('2017-08-18 00:00:00.000', '2017-08-11 11:13:48.490', '2017-08-24 14:47:56.660', '037-01714223-REF-1'),
    ('2017-08-18 00:00:00.000', '2017-08-11 11:13:31.553', '2017-08-24 14:47:56.630', '037-01714223-REF-1'),
    ('2017-08-18 00:00:00.000', '2017-08-11 11:13:39.410', '2017-08-24 14:47:56.567', '037-01714223-REF-1'),
    (NULL, '2017-08-15 11:14:00.623', '2017-08-15 14:03:15.067', '037-01714223-REF-1'),
    (NULL, '2017-08-11 11:13:36.537', '2017-08-14 12:45:13.103', '037-01714223-REF-1'),
    (NULL, '2017-08-11 11:13:45.363', '2017-08-14 12:45:05.057', '037-01714223-REF-1'),
    (NULL, '2017-08-11 11:13:44.007', '2017-08-14 12:44:58.027', '037-01714223-REF-1'),
    (NULL, '2017-08-11 11:13:28.833', '2017-08-14 12:44:50.620', '037-01714223-REF-1'),
    (NULL, '2017-08-11 11:13:48.490', '2017-08-14 12:44:43.387', '037-01714223-REF-1'),
    (NULL, '2017-08-11 11:13:31.553', '2017-08-14 12:44:36.353', '037-01714223-REF-1'),
    (NULL, '2017-08-11 11:13:39.410', '2017-08-14 12:44:28.450', '037-01714223-REF-1'),
    (NULL, '2017-08-11 11:13:40.113', '2017-08-14 12:44:21.230', '037-01714223-REF-1'),
    (NULL, '2017-08-11 11:13:45.990', '2017-08-14 12:44:13.730', '037-01714223-REF-1'),
    (NULL, '2017-08-11 11:13:41.240', '2017-08-14 12:44:06.823', '037-01714223-REF-1'),
    (NULL, '2017-08-11 11:13:41.457', '2017-08-14 12:43:59.370', '037-01714223-REF-1'),
    (NULL, '2017-08-11 11:13:37.553', '2017-08-14 12:43:51.730', '037-01714223-REF-1'),
    (NULL, '2017-08-11 11:13:40.707', '2017-08-14 12:43:44.527', '037-01714223-REF-1'),
    ('2017-08-18 00:00:00.000', '2017-08-15 11:14:00.623', '2017-08-24 14:49:45.850', '037-01714223-REF-2'),
    ('2017-08-18 00:00:00.000', '2017-08-11 11:13:31.553', '2017-08-24 14:48:52.287', '037-01714223-REF-2'),
    ('2017-08-18 00:00:00.000', '2017-08-11 11:13:44.007', '2017-08-24 14:48:45.927', '037-01714223-REF-2'),
    ('2017-08-18 00:00:00.000', '2017-08-11 11:13:28.833', '2017-08-24 14:48:39.287', '037-01714223-REF-2'),
    ('2017-08-18 00:00:00.000', '2017-08-11 11:13:48.490', '2017-08-24 14:48:32.847', '037-01714223-REF-2'),
    ('2017-08-18 00:00:00.000', '2017-08-11 11:13:39.410', '2017-08-24 14:48:26.253', '037-01714223-REF-2'),
    ('2017-08-18 00:00:00.000', '2017-08-11 11:13:44.007', '2017-08-24 14:47:56.753', '037-01714223-REF-2'),
    ('2017-08-18 00:00:00.000', '2017-08-11 11:13:28.833', '2017-08-24 14:47:56.723', '037-01714223-REF-2'),
    ('2017-08-18 00:00:00.000', '2017-08-11 11:13:48.490', '2017-08-24 14:47:56.660', '037-01714223-REF-2'),
    ('2017-08-18 00:00:00.000', '2017-08-11 11:13:31.553', '2017-08-24 14:47:56.630', '037-01714223-REF-2'),
    ('2017-08-18 00:00:00.000', '2017-08-11 11:13:39.410', '2017-08-24 14:47:56.567', '037-01714223-REF-2'),
    (NULL, '2017-08-15 11:14:00.623', '2017-08-15 14:03:15.067', '037-01714223-REF-2'),
    (NULL, '2017-08-11 11:13:36.537', '2017-08-14 12:45:13.103', '037-01714223-REF-2'),
    (NULL, '2017-08-11 11:13:45.363', '2017-08-14 12:45:05.057', '037-01714223-REF-2'),
    (NULL, '2017-08-11 11:13:44.007', '2017-08-14 12:44:58.027', '037-01714223-REF-2'),
    (NULL, '2017-08-11 11:13:28.833', '2017-08-14 12:44:50.620', '037-01714223-REF-2'),
    (NULL, '2017-08-11 11:13:48.490', '2017-08-14 12:44:43.387', '037-01714223-REF-2'),
    (NULL, '2017-08-11 11:13:31.553', '2017-08-14 12:44:36.353', '037-01714223-REF-2'),
    (NULL, '2017-08-11 11:13:39.410', '2017-08-14 12:44:28.450', '037-01714223-REF-2');

-- SELECT * FROM #TestData td;

--============================================================================================================

SELECT 
    UpdatedOn = CAST(SUBSTRING(MAX(bv.BinaryValue), 5, 8) AS DATETIME),
    td.rescd_PurchaseOrderLine
FROM 
    #TestData td
    CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (CAST(td.RN AS BINARY(4)) + CAST(td.UpdatedOn AS BINARY(8))) ) bv (BinaryValue)
WHERE 
    td.cd_POLineItemScheduledShipDate IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY 
    td.rescd_PurchaseOrderLine;
```

Results...

```
UpdatedOn               rescd_PurchaseOrderLine
----------------------- -----------------------
2017-08-24 14:47:56.567 037-01714223-REF-1
2017-08-24 14:47:56.567 037-01714223-REF-2
```

Comment: This did it, Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't too complicated, but your requirement is ambiguous:

> I am trying to get the UpdatedOn date from the row with the first instance of the cd_POLineItemScheduledShipDate not being NULL.

In the above sentence, the word "first" is not defined. Tables are considered unordered unless you specify a sort order.

Assuming we want to order by update date, a query would look like:

```
SELECT MIN(UpdatedOn) UpdatedOn
FROM Shadow 
WHERE cd_POLineItemScheduledShipDate  IS NULL
```

If you wanted to order by something else (e.g. creation date) it's only slightly more complicated:

```
SELECT TOP 1 UpdatedOn
FROM Shadow
WHERE cd_POLineItemScheduledShipDate  IS NULL
ORDER BY CreatedOn
```

If you need one row in the resultset per value of `_rescd_PurchaseOrderLine` you can group:

```
SELECT MIN(UpdatedOn) UpdatedOn, _rescd_PurchaseOrderLine
FROM Shadow 
WHERE cd_POLineItemScheduledShipDate  IS NULL
GROUP BY _rescd_PurchaseOrderLine
```

or

```
SELECT FIRST_VALUE(UpdatedOn) OVER (ORDER BY CreatedOn) UpdatedOn,
       _rescd_PurchaseOrderLine
FROM Shadow
WHERE cd_POLineItemScheduledShipDate  IS NULL
GROUP BY _rescd_PurchaseOrderLine
```

Comment: This almost works. I need one `UpdatedOn` value per PurchaseOrderLine. When i run this it gets the correct date for the first number *037-01714223-REF-1*, but for the second number *037-01714223-REF-2* it does not. I do have it ordered by the `UpdatedOn DESC` and for the second number is pulls the second oldest date instead of the min date.

Comment: Added some clarification to my question.